# More efficient way to map logic matrix (false/true) to uint8 matrix (0/255)?

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

I have a 2d array of boolean values and I want to map false to 0 (uint8) and true to 255(uint8) so that I can use the matrix as a b/w image.

Currently I have:

```
uint8matrix = boolMatrix.astype(numpy.uint8)*255
```

but I think the multiplication is adding unnecessary computation.

Comment: I presume this is numpy?

Comment: Yes. I have edited to make it more clear.

Comment: Same idea as yours, but `boolMatrix * np.uint8(255)` seems to be a bit more efficient. But I can't think of anything better really.

Comment: scalar multiplication is not that expensive process.

Comment: @Reti43, it is about three times faster on a decent sized data set

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I'll be using @Reti43's suggestion and will try to see where else I can optimize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bool implicitly casts to int in numpy; so simply multiplying with np.uint8(255) will do the trick, and save you an extra pass over the data.

Answer (score 2):

for tuning, Cython, or simpler for python users Numba, can give you sensible improvement :

```
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def cast(mat):
    mat2=empty_like(mat,uint8)
    for i in range(mat.shape[0]):
        for j in range(mat.shape[1]):
            if mat[i,j] : mat2[i,j]=255
            else : mat2[i,j]=0
    return mat2
```

Some tests on a 1000x1000 random matrix:

```
In [20]: %timeit boolMatrix*uint8(255)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.46 ms per loop

In [21]: %timeit cast(boolMatrix)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.3 ms per loop
```